# AVFoundation: How to write video to file in real time instead of using exportAsync?

Tags: swift, swift2, avfoundation

AVFoundation has been quite a struggle for me because most of the examples and documentation out there are in Obj-c.. As my title states, I would like to write to file in real time instead of calling exportAsync once the user has finished recording their video.

If anyone can offer some advice or documentation on how to do this it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear where your video is coming from, but`exportAsync` makes it sound like you're using `AVAssetExportSession` with an existing file or composition.

1. capture your video (and audio?) frames
   a. if from an existing composition or file, with `AVAssetReader`
   b. if from the camera, with `AVCaptureSession` etc
2. progressively write the frames to file using `AVAssetWriter` & `AVAssetWriterInput`

If you're expecting the writing to file to be interrupted for some reason,
consider setting the `AVAssetWriter`'s `movieFragmentInterval` property to something small .